# TeX Live 2019 install hangs, want to resume

Tags: texlive, installing, ctan, texlive-2019

I have installed various implementations of TeX countless times over the years. I know it can be difficult. But the problem I have now is maddening.

I am running on fiber internet, gig up gig down. So it's not my connection. I have tried all the mirrors. But no matter what I do, the TeX Live install hangs, usually deep into the 3836 packages it needs to install. I'd download an .iso but everyone seems to recommend against it.

How can I resume? Redownloading everything is annoying and time-consuming, as I'm limited strictly by the mirrors' bandwidth. And my directory is nearly complete. I find it mind-boggling that a resume capability is not somehow possible for this package in 2019. If so, maybe I need to switch distributions to something that is easier to get going.

Also, how annoying is it to not be able to respond to your own thread? Stackexhange needs to do away with "rep". I'm probably almost twice as old as the forum mods, I've earned the right to be annoyed by something so pointless and counterproductive.

Yes, I'm running win10.

Comment: I ran into trouble using MS-Windows 10. Is that your operating system ?

Comment: Yes, I'm running win 10.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: My proc is 64bits. I fixed the issue changing C:\Windows\System32 by C:\Windows\SysWOW64 both in COMSPEC and PATH environment variables . No guaranties that this works for an other machine.

Comment: You can try installing the minimal scheme instead of full and then running `tlmgr install scheme-full` and `tlmgr path add`. That will install TL locally with its management utilities and everything else can be installed without having to reinstall everything.

Comment: Download the iso and install it. The shortcomings of Windows are not worth time and effort.